# How to prevent the browser window from Zooming

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I want to prevent the zoom functionality of browser. My problem is I have a OnRezise method which controls the size of a div in my page. This is working as expected. But while zooming I need to disable the resize of this div. Is it possible.

My code is like this

```
<body onresize="doResize();" onload="ctlLoad();">
```

My Javascript is like this

```
function doResize() {
objControl = document.getElementById("targetContainer");
container = document.getElementById("livePlayerContainer");

if (browserZoomLevel != (window.screen.deviceXDPI / 96)) {
    objControl.style.width = objControl.style.width + "px";
    objControl.style.height = objControl.style.height + "px";

    container.style.width = container.style.width + "px";
    container.style.height = container.style.height + "px";
    return;
}

//minHeight = 600;
minHeight = 420;
maxHeight = 1100;
maxWidth = 1000;

var winW = 0, winH = 0, ControlWidth = 637, ControlHeight = 480;
if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
    //Non-IE
    winW = window.innerWidth;
    winH = window.innerHeight;
} else
    if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
        //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
        winW = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        winH = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
        //IE 4 compatible
        winW = document.body.clientWidth;
        winH = document.body.clientHeight;
    }

// **NOTE - This is the main value to change. as you increase this value, it will add space to the bottom of the page
//          If we add more controls below the activeX, this value will need to be increased as well
ControlHeight = winH - 168;
ControlWidth = 4 * ControlHeight / 3;

//So it doesn't go out of bounds with the width
if (ControlWidth + 218 > winW) {
    ControlWidth = winW - 218;
    ControlHeight = 3 * ControlWidth / 4;
}

objControl.style.width = ControlWidth + "px";
objControl.style.height = ControlHeight + "px";

container.style.width = ControlWidth + "px";
container.style.height = ControlHeight + "px";

var num = parseInt($('#multiplexNumber').val());
ChangeDisplayMode(num, null);

}
```

I tried to retain the required div's size same as it by using this code

```
if (browserZoomLevel != (window.screen.deviceXDPI / 96)) {
    objControl.style.width = objControl.style.width + "px";
    objControl.style.height = objControl.style.height + "px";

    container.style.width = container.style.width + "px";
    container.style.height = container.style.height + "px";
    return;
}
```

But it is not working. Can somebody help me for solving this?

Comment: `vw` and `vh` prevents from zooming. But you want to see if you want that.

Comment: I am sorry I am not clear with vw and vh.

Comment: [vw, vh: Respectively these are 1/100th of the width of the viewport, and 1/100th of the height of the viewport.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units) Also usable for `font-size`.

Comment: don't your mean this (browserZoomLevel != =(window.screen.deviceXDPI / 96)).... place break points in your code with the f12 dev tool.